# Ethernet PHY/MAC/SWITCH IC available?

Tags: switches, ethernet, mac, phy

I'm wanting to use an ethernet switch/Phy LAN9303 to output 2, maybe 3 ethernet signals. I know that I need a 25MHz clock, supporting resistors and caps as well as the magnetics, but I want to know if there's a way to get around having to use an FPGA or processor for the MAC - or do I have the concept completely wrong? Is there an IC that has the PHY and MAC (and maybe the switch) all in one? Thanks

Comment: I designed a MAC chip for IBM's Token Ring 802.5 in 1983, a Token Bus 802.4 MAC chip for GE in 1985, and the first PC Ethernet board for IBM.  By now there should be a chip. Ethernet was easy. Worst networking MAC protocol ever, but simple. So simple, an entire industry (i.e. Cisco) was built to band-aid the inept protocol.

Answer (score 1):

There are switch IC's that use external phys (you need to have a separate MII interface that goes to a phy), switch IC's that have internal phys (the differential pairs run right into the IC), and switch IC's that do both internal and external.

A good example of this is the [KSZ8873MLL/FLL/RLL](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002348A.pdf)

Depending on the IC you buy the Phys can be external or internal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the [LAN9352](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00001923A.pdf) has 2 PHYs, switch, built-in MAC and host SPI interface.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Integrated MAC+PHYs are common. Integrated switch+PHYs are common. I've never run across all three in one chip, but I wouldn't be surprised if they exist.  I'm not going to give specific part recommendations because EE.SE discourages "shopping" questions, but they're easy to find with a Google search.